# Double Integral Evaluation Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The question is:

> Evaluate the following double integral $\int\int 2xy dA$ bounded by $y= 1−x^2,y= 1 +x$ and $y= 0$ in the $xy$ plane

I keep getting $-1/12$. Pretty sure this is wrong since you cannot have negative volume. I get the same answer regardless if I treat the x or y plane as a simple graph. Thanks!

Comment: Is that first equation supposed to be $y=1-2x$ or $y=1-x^2$?

Comment: Who told you that is a volume of something?

Comment: How are you getting $-1/12$? Show your work and write the question in the question, [not the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144). Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: @scoopfaze my bad, $x^2$

Comment: Yes, the result is $\;-\cfrac1{12}\;$

Comment: $y=1-x^2, y=1+x,y=0$ determine two bounded regions, and it is not clear without some additional info which of them should be used. (Two or three, depending on how you count.) Show your work, how exactly you get your answer, the questions is not clearly stated because 1. the region is not clearly specified, and 2. it is not clear what you have done, and what might have gone wrong. Anybody attempting to answer would have to speculate and make extra assumptions on their own.

Comment: @Mirko The region described is $y\le 1-x^2$ and $y\le 1+x$ and $y\ge0$

Comment: @user140776 1. how do you know? 2. if you are correct, then either you or the OP should edit their question and specify and clarify

Comment: @Mirko The region I gave seems most plausible since the $x$ axis is listed as one of the bounding curves.

Comment: @user140776 yes, it is most plausible, I agree ... nevertheless I think the OP could have done a better job in describing (a) the problem and (b) their work.

Comment: There is no reason to believe the answer represents a volume, just like integrals on the real line can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Im getting $\frac{1}{12}$. Assuming the region that you are referring to is $y\le 1-x^2$ and $y\le 1+x$ and $y\ge0$, which seems the most plausible since you say that one of the bounding curves is the $x-$axis. It is more convenient to integrate first w.r.t.  $x$ then w.r.t $y$. I get:

\begin{align}\int_0^1 \int_{y-1}^{\sqrt{1-y}}2xydxdy &= \int_0^{1} [x^2y]_{y-1}^{\sqrt{1-y}}dy\\
&= \int_0^1(y^2-y^3)dy\\
&=\left[\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{4}\right]_0^1\\
&=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\\
&=\frac{1}{12} \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to expect a positive answer for every double integral.

The region of integration is partially in the second quadrant.

Note that the integrand $2xy$ is negative in the second quadrant thus it is quite right if your result in negative.

Also make sure you get the limits correctly.

Comment: OH, i did not know this, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani  Doesnt the region span both the second AND first quadrants? Because it says it is bounded by $1-x^2$, $1+x$ AND the x-axis.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The region has most of it in the first quadrant. I did not pay attention to the graph carefully.